# Running Tasks When Specified Time Passes the Stored Dates (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, scheduled-tasks

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that uses SQL Server as database. The app uses "jobs" as base entities, and each job has multiple dates such as creation date, approval date, delivery date, etc.

I am looking for the best practice for the following scenario: When for instance 3 days passes the stored creation date, and the proposal is not answered, the proposal should be re-sent. How can I accomplish this without using any Windows services?

Comment: `without using any Windows services`.  Why?  That's a fairly simple and solid option.  The only other reliable option that comes to mind is using the task scheduler.  Both options don't work in a hosted environment where you have no access to the OS.

Comment: I need a solution without using any Windows services because our web app is running in a hosted environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule tasks in a number of ways:

- You can use the Windows Task Scheduler.

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler
- You run scheduled jobs within SQL Server via it's built-in support for job scheduling. Configured properly, SQL Server can even email job notifications, or raise alerts for operations.

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

If neither of those work, you can install one of any number of [`cron(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cron&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) ports/clones/workalikes:

- http://cronw.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.nncron.ru/index.shtml
- http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2012/05/free-utility-a-simple-task-scheduler-for-windows/
- http://www.visualcron.com/
- http://www.z-cron.com/
- http://www.wincron.com/
- etc.

But all these schedulers do is start a job. It's up to you to write the job to actually do the work. In your example,

> When for instance 3 days passes the stored creation date,
>   and the proposal is not answered, the proposal should be re-sent.

You're going to have to right something — a stored procedure, a console app, a powershell script, etc. — that knows how to find the proposals that have been sitting around for three days without an answer. Then it needs to re-send each proposal. You probably need to mark them somehow as re-sent, etc.

All the scheduler does is fire off the job. For this, the job probably just needs to run once per day, right? That's the easy part.

Comment: Actually, I need a solution which sends the proposal again when it has been *exactly* 3 days since the creation date. But I guess, I'd need a solution to check every job every minute or second, which does not sound possible or rational. I don't know.

Comment: Why not? The problem with the task scheduler or cron, is that it spawns a spawns a new process when the scheduler event fires. A service would be a better choice &mdash; and they're not that hard to write in C#: see this [walk-through on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx). All you'd do in the `OnStart` event is create a timer that fires however often you want to poll. The timer tick handler then needs to do the actual work.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, but our app is running in a hosted environment. Any suggestions for hosted environments?